# How to implement speech recognition using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I have successfully implemented a speech recognition app by using SpeechRecognizer, it was very easy to get started. but then, I realized that its performance is not satisfactory to what I wanted.

So I decided to try the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API, to see if it meets my expectations, but I'm not finding an easy way to start with it. I've been looking for an Android SDK to install on my project, but with no luck.

Does anyone know how I can get started with it on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has an example guide for building Android apps that use the speech & translation APIs [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/speech-translation-android-microservice).

Comment: I found this example here -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech

But Im gonna set your answer as accepted